# rails 3 - accepts nested attributes for before destroy validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have a teachers model that accepts_nested_attributes_for klasses. I don't want to be able to delete the klass if there are users in the klass and I want to print a validation message.

This is what I have...

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :klasses, :reject_if => proc { |a| a['name'].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :teacher
    has_many :users
    before_destroy :reject_if_has_users

    private 

    def reject_if_has_users
      if users.length > 0
        errors.add_to_base "You cannot delete this class as it contains users."
        false
      else
        true
      end
    end

end
```

I want the validation to fail when I try removing a klass from a teacher that contains users when I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for and passing in a "klasses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"test", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"17183"} hash.

The above method will prevent the klass from being removed if I don't have the error.add_to_base line. It won't however cause a validation message to be shown. When I have that line, it doesn't prevent the deletion.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation doesn't take place when deleting a record, only when saving a record. The way I handled this in one of my projects is raising an exception in the model and then rescueing from that exception in my controller and showing a flash alert. Like this:

Model:

```
class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :reject_if_has_users

  private 

  def reject_if_has_users
    raise "You cannot delete this class as it contains users." if users.length > 0
  end
end
```

Teachers controller:

```
def update
  # Code for updating the teacher
rescue RuntimeError => e
  redirect_to teacher_url(@teacher, :alert => e.message) and return false
end
```

Comment: I am not calling the destroy method, I am saving the teacher record that can include a hash of deleted klasses that get removed magically by accepts_nested_attributes_for. eg.  "klasses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"test", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"17183"}

Comment: Hm, sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. I will rewrite my answer...

Comment: I updated my answer, but it's not very clean. You should add some comments to the code making clear what is going on. I'd be interested to see a better solution. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Mischa, that seems to make sense but when I try it, I get an error message .... syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('.  I tried taking out the e parameter in the RuntimeError block and hardcoded an error message and I get the same result as before. That is, it won't delete the klass but it wont produce a validation error either.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, it should be `RuntimeError => e`. I guess you can't just add an error via `add_to_base` and expect it to be shown. The `Teacher` record you are saving has to be marked invalid too. You could do what I suggested before: rescue the expection in the `TeachersController` and show the error as a flash message.

Comment: Cheers, that worked. I also needed to return false. I will update your answer.